# Turtle Graphics with Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, fractals

I need to draw a shape using recursion and turtle graphics.

I'm more of a looper and rarely ever use recursion, so some help here with this would be nice. Not even sure where to start.

The shape just needs to be cool looking.

Comment: Welcome to SE, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm not sure where to start, so a beginning would be awesome if anyone could help me and the rest I can attempt.

Comment: Have a look to http://www.kidscoderepo.com/python.html, it is a good point to start and meets your cool looking requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any parametrization, here a beginning:

```
import time
from turtle import *

def recurse(n):
    if n>0:
        left(10)
        forward(5)
        recurse(n-1)

recurse(20)
time.sleep(5)
```

When you create recursive function, you need to have a stop criterion that effectively guaranties your program will exit at some point.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I think I'm on the right track now.

Answer (score 1):

Oh man! What a fun problem :)

As you are a self-proclaimed 'looper', I would think about recursion just as you would looping.

In a `for` loop, you execute the body of the loop until the `for` loop condition is satisfied. Now, recursion is very similar. You keep calling the function until the parameters of the function no longer hit a recursive case. They hit a base case instead which then returns a value that the recursion can then build up on.

So thinking about recursion this way, let's think about how to draw a square. You need to first identify what parts of the code get repeated (i.e. what would be in the body of a `for` loop trying to do the same thing). Then, identify when you want this repetition to stop (i.e. how do I know when a `for` loop exits).

While drawing a square, I can think of two major things that get repeated at least 4 times. The turtle goes forward a certain number of steps and the turtle turns 90 degrees (or 270 degrees depending on orientation). So this would be something we detail in our recursive case.

Now, let's think about the base case. Well, we know that a square has 4 sides, so after the turtle draws four sides, we want it to stop.

Lastly, let's think about the function declaration and how these two pieces, the recursive case and the base case, play into it. A function declaration may take the following form (in Python):

```
def draw_square_recursive(turn_deg=90, side_len, sides=4):
    """ 
    Function draws a square with turtle graphics recursively 

    :param turn_deg: an int, the number of degrees a turtle should turn
    :param side_len: an int, the length of a side of the square
    :param sides: an int, the number of sides in our square
    """
```

`turn_deg` and `side_len` will be important for our recursive case as they define how a turtle should turn and how far it should 'walk'. `sides` is an interesting parameter and one we can use to dictate whether to continue recurring or stop. If we subtract 1 from `sides` every time we draw a side, we will know that we need to stop recurring when `sides == 0`, a base case!
Thus, whenever we call our function to recur again, we will call it as, `draw_square_recursive(side_len, sides-1):`

Overall, the structure of the function would look like:

```
def draw_square_recursive(turn_deg=90, side_len, sides=4):
    """ 
    Function draws a square with turtle graphics recursively 

    :param turn_deg: an int, the number of degrees a turtle should turn
    :param side_len: an int, the length of a side of the square
    :param sides: an int, the number of sides in our square
    """
    if sides == 0:
        # base case!
    else:
        # recursive case!
```

Note that this function named `draw_square_recursive` but it can be much more generalized to other shapes. Do you see how?

Sorry if this was a long winded answer! Hope it helps ;p

Answer (score 0):

More editorial than answer, but recursion like this:

```
def recurse(n):
    if n>0:
        left(10)
        forward(5)
        recurse(n-1)
```

which is better written as iteration:

```
for n in range(2):
    left(10)
    forward(5)
```

is similar to folks who ask, "How can I count the number of elements in a list using recursion?"  Ditto drawing a square using recursion.

I understand the goal is to learn about recursion, but what seems to get lost is that there are times where recursion makes wonderful things happen and times where it just slows down your program.  Fractals are an opportunity to so something of wonder with recursion:

```
import sys
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def hilbert_curve(n, turtle, angle=90):
    if n <= 0:
        return

    turtle.left(angle)
    hilbert_curve(n - 1, turtle, -angle)
    turtle.forward(1)
    turtle.right(angle)
    hilbert_curve(n - 1, turtle, angle)
    turtle.forward(1)
    hilbert_curve(n - 1, turtle, angle)
    turtle.right(angle)
    turtle.forward(1)
    hilbert_curve(n - 1, turtle, -angle)
    turtle.left(angle)

depth = int(sys.argv[1])
size = 2 ** depth

screen = Screen()
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, size, size)

yertle = Turtle('turtle')
yertle.speed('fastest')
yertle.penup()
yertle.goto(0.5, 0.5)
yertle.pendown()

hilbert_curve(depth, yertle)

yertle.hideturtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

**USAGE**

```
% python3 hilbert.py 5
```

**(PARTIAL) OUTPUT**

[image]

I'm not picking on the other answers, I'm suggesting you think big (or at least beyond "just needs to be cool looking".)